# Import an XML into app-properties.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, applicationcontext

So, I have my pom.xml which imports a different project and creates a jar of it. I want to access an application-context.xml file which is there in the other project.

Eq: Project A is being imported by my Project B. I want to access the application-context.xml file in Project A. Any pointers on how I could do that in my application-context.xml file?

```
<import resource="??"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<import resource="classpath:/from/root/of/classpath/file.xml"/>
```

assuming `file.xml` will be placed in runtime classpath at `/from/root/of/classpath` path from root of classpath

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the `app-properties.xml` file is under `META-INF` folder within your Project B class path :

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/app-properties.xml"/>
```